# Does it possible to upload certificate to portal via code?

Tags: c#, azure, iot, x509certificate, azure-iot-hub

I'm setting a new device on Azure IoT devices, and instead of uploading certification manually i want to be able upload it via code.

I created an Azure IoT device with SSL authentication, i have created the certification in the back end, got the primary thumbprint and the second one.
And to the best of my understanding the this certification need to upload to the Azure portal.

And instead of uploading certification manually i want to be able upload it via code.
Does it possible? or each time i need to upload it manually?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the rest API to upload the certificate to the IoT hub. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iothub/certificates/createorupdate. You can use it to add new or replace existing certificate.

Comment: @avisiboni If the answer helpful you could mark it by clicking on the checkbox beside your question. Thanks